# iText signature OcspClient failed to get OCSP

Tags: pdf, itext, bouncycastle, ocsp

I have A3 certificate in a smart card from icpbr when I try sign PDF with iText
I get this error:
**c.i.t.p.s.OcspClientBouncyCastle INFO  Getting OCSP from http://io-ocsp-icpbr.imprensaoficial.com.br
com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.OcspClientBouncyCastle ERROR io-ocsp-icpbr.imprensaoficial.com.br**

I use the code of this link:
[Digital signatures - chapter 4](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security/digital-signatures-white-paper/digital-signatures-chapter-4)

File: C4_01_SignWithPKCS11HSM.java

I checked that http://io-ocsp-icpbr.imprensaoficial.com.br don't have OCSP active.
how to skip OCSP request?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want iText to make OCSP requests, don't give it an OCSP client to make them with, i.e. use `null` instead of an `OcspClientBouncyCastle` instance as OCSP client in the `OcspClient ocspClient` parameter.